# How to pass variables from jquery fetch function to symfony routes.yaml?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, routes, symfony4

So I want to call a controller in symfony by passing in my route declared in routes.yaml with a jquery fetch function and I want to pass to variables from jquery to the controller. How can I do that ?

Here's my jquery. I call this route and I want to pass the two variable on top with it.

```
var longitudde = lonLat[0];
var latudde = lonLat[1];
fetch('/weather_request)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  // ...
});
```

To pass those variables to routes.yaml in Symfony:

```
weather_request:
    path:     /weather_request
    controller: App\Controller\WeatherController::weather
    methods: [get]
    defaults:
      longitude: longitude
      latitude: latitude
```

To finaly pass them in the weather function in WeatherController:

```
public function weather($longitude, $latitude)
{
    return $this->render('weather/index.html.twig', ['weatherInfos' => $this->weatherService->getWeather($longitude, $latitude)]);
}
```

So how can I pass the longitude and latitude from jquery fetch to the controller here ? I'm new to Symfony so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: do you get any error this way ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI No I just dont pass anything ti the url

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can help you :

```
  $.ajax({
  url: '{{path('weather_request')}}',
  type: 'GET',
  data: { 
  longitude: lonLat[0], 
  latutide: lonLat[1], 
  },
  success: function(response) {
    //called when successful
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    //console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

In your controller :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function weather(Request $request)
{
  if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {         
   $longitude = $request->query->get('longitude');
   $latutide  =  $request->query->get('latutide');
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I use it like that:
In Js:

```js
const obj = {
"longitudde":lonLat[0],
"latudde":lonLat[1]
}

fetch('/weather_request', 
{
     method:'POST',
         headers: { 
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
     },
     body:JSON.stringify(obj)
 }).then(resp => {
         return resp.json();
 }).then(res => {
         console.log(res)      
     //...
})
}
```

In Controller route annotations,but you can use with Route.yaml:

```js
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
* @Route("/weather_request", methods={"POST"})
*
*/
public function weather(Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $longitude = $data->longitudde;
    $latitude = $data->latudde;
    return $this->render('weather/index.html.twig', 
    [
        'weatherInfos' => $this->weatherService
                          ->getWeather($longitude, $latitude)
    ]);   
}
```